# Re-populate fields after form submission and redirection PHP ONLY

Tags: php, session, redirect, session-variables, populate

I am supposed to have my form elements repopulate using php and html only after I click the link from page two. However, none of the fields are repopulating. Please help me!!?

Page 1:

```
    <?php
session_start();
?>
<?php

/*
This page should:

1) Use a cookie (NOT PHP SESSION) that expires a year from now to do the following:
Record the timestamp of the FIRST load of this page (but NOT any subsequent load of this page).

Note: You only need first 3 parameters in setcookie() for this HW.

2) If the suvey was already completed, transfer to third page (thank you page).
That page instructs you to set a cookie that will allow you to detect this.

Recall from the CRUD example how page transfers are done in PHP:
header("Location: URL");

3) The form in this page should submit to THIS PAGE, and then transfer to hw_page2.php
after saving stuff to PHPs built-in $_SESSION superglobal.
The data will then be available in all the other pages (remember no database is allowed for this HW).

4) If the button in the 2nd page is clicked to come back to this page, the
Session data should re-populate into the form.


*/


if (!isset($_COOKIE['load_date'])) {
    setcookie('load_date', time(), time() + (86400 * 365));
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>User Profile</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h3><?=$message?></h3>
     User Profile:
     <?php
     $load_date = $_COOKIE['load_date'];
     $_SESSION['is_cool'] = $_POST['is_cool'];
     $_SESSION['like_bands'] = $_POST['like_bands'];
     $_SESSION['other_band'] = $_POST['other_band'];

     $is_cool = $_SESSION['is_cool'];
     $bands = $_SESSION['like_bands'];
     $other_band = $_SESSION['other_band'];

     print_r($bands);
     echo $other_band;
     echo $is_cool;
     ?>

     <br><br>
     <form action="hw_page1.php" method="POST" name="form1" onsubmit="return validate_form()">
      <input type="hidden" name="task" value="process_profile">

      <input type="checkbox" name="is_cool" value= "yes" <?php if ($is_cool == 'yes') {
         echo 'checked = "yes"';
     }?>>
         Are you cool?

       <br><br>
       What Bands do you like?
       <br>
       <select name="like_bands[]" multiple>  <small>* Required Field</small>
          <option value="Sabbath" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['like_bands']) && in_array("Mastodon", $bands)) {
              echo 'selected';
          }  ?>> Black Sabbath</option>
          <option value="Mastodon" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['like_bands']) && in_array("Mastodon", $bands)) {
         echo 'selected';
     } ?> >Mastodon</option>
          <option value="Metallica" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['like_bands']) && in_array("Metallica", $bands)) {
         echo 'selected';
     } ?> >Metallica</option>
         <option value="Swift" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['like_bands']) && in_array("Swift", $bands)) {
         echo 'selected';
     } ?> >Taylor Swift</option>
       </select>
       <br><br>
       Favorite band not in the above list.
       <br>
       <input type="text" name="other_band" value="<?=$other_band?>">
       <br><br>
       <button type="submit" name= 'submit' value = 'submit'> Continue/Confirm </button>
     </form>

     <script>
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      // Client-side form validation
      // Don't change the names of stuff in the form, and you won't have to change anything below
      // Used built-in JS instead of JQuery or other validation tool
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      function validate_form() {

        var form_obj = document.form1;

        var count_liked = 0;
        for (var i=0 ; i < form_obj['like_bands[]'].options.length ; i++ ) {
          if (form_obj['like_bands[]'].options[i].selected) {
            count_liked++;
          }
        }

        if (count_liked == 0) {
          alert("You must choose a band from the menu.");
          return false; // cancel form submission
        }

        return true;  // trigger form submission
      }
    </script>

    <?php
    $_SESSION['is_cool'] = $is_cool;
    $_SESSION['like_bands'] = $bands;
    $_SESSION['other_band'] = $other_band;
    echo $_SESSION['is_cool'];
    if (isset($_SESSION['like_bands'])) {
        header('Location: hw_page2.php');
    }
    ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

My second Page:

```
    <?php
session_start();
/*
This page should:
1) Transfer back to hw_page1.php if loaded directly without the survey being completed (no survey data in session).
2) Display the Survey Data submitted from the previous page.

3) The form in this page should submit to THIS PAGE.
Use PHP to validate that the form below is completed.
  Validate that the signature is not the empty string or only blank spaces (use PHP trim() function)
  And of course validate that the checkbox was checked.
If the validation passes, save the signature into SESSION ande transfer to hw_page3.php.
If the validation fails, don't transfer.
  Instead, back through to the form in this page WITH an appropriate message.
  In that case, the Survey Data MUST also re-display in this page.

Note:
  hw_page1.php used client-side JavaScript validation to ensure that all data was collected.
  For the form below. do NOT use client-side JavaScript validation, but rather use PHP as instructed above.
  Client-side validation is convenient for the end user, but can be bypassed by someone with know-how.
*/
?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['is_cool']) and !isset($_SESSION['like_bands'])) {
    header('Location: hw_page1.php');
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Verify Profile</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
  $is_cool = $_SESSION['is_cool'];
  $bands = $_SESSION['like_bands'];
  $other_band = $_SESSION['other_band'];
  echo $is_cool;
  print_r($bands);
  echo  $other_band;
  $_SESSION['is_cool'] = $is_cool;
  $_SESSION['like_bands'] = $bands;
  $_SESSION['other_band'] = $other_band;
  $bandslist = "";
  foreach ($bands as $band) {
      $bandslist .= "$band, ";
  }
  ?>
    <!-- Display Survey Data Here -->
  <table width="" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
      <tr  valign="top">
          <td>Are you cool?</td>
          <td>Liked Bands</td>
          <td>Other Favorite Band</td>
      </tr>
      <tr  valign="top">
          <td><?= $_SESSION['is_cool']; ?></td>
          <td><?= $bandslist; ?></td>
          <td><?= $other_band; ?></td>
      </tr>
  </table>


    <br><br>
    <form action="hw_page2.php" method="GET" >
      Verify that your profile data shown above is accurate by signing below.
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="signature" value="" placeholder="Sign Here">
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="user_certify" value="yes">
      I certify, under penalty of purgery, that my profile is accurate.
      <br><br>
      <button type="button" onclick="window.location='hw_page1.php';"> Go Back: Edit Profile Before Signing </button>
      <!-- This is NOT a Submit Button! -->
      <br>
      <button type="submit"> Record Profile </button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <!-- This is obviously -->
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me figure out where I am making a mistake! I have been working on it for days but I cannot figure out the answer.

Comment: In your first page, check if your `$_POST` variables are actually set before you assign them to your session variables. When coming from your second page `$_POST` is _not_ set

Comment: How would I set the $_POST when leaving the second page? I have tried to echo my session variables and they do save m, but only when I do not redirect from the second page. 

Comment: You don't! Your session variables would already be set when coming from the second page, no need to re-set them

Comment: Oh okay I see, if that is the case then the code above should be working. It all works like a dream when I remove the header(Location:) line at the bottom but as soon as I uncomment that, everything breaks!

Comment: It would only be working when `$_POST` is set, which it isn't when redirecting or clicking the link from your second page. As I said in my first comment, make sure `$_POST` is set before `$_SESSION['is_cool'] = $_POST['is_cool'];` and setting the other sessions. Good luck